# PhpStorm HTTP client. Unable to pass POST params to localhost

Tags: http, post, phpstorm

I've just discovered to myself an PhpStorm HTTP client tool, but immediately faced unexpected problem. I am unable to send any POST params to my localhost.

I've tried the following code:

```
POST https://test.loc/
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "test": "asd"
}
```

Didn't work. The `$_REQUEST` array is simply empty.

At the same time, i'm receiving all GET params without problems.

Also tried to send exactly same request to `https://httpbin.org/post` and received the list of my params back at responce, so I assume that request syntax is ok and HTTP client work well.

So, could anyone please tell what the problem with my local server?

I'm using:

- PhpStorm 2020.3.1
- Open Server 5.3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has nothing to do with PhpStorm. It's just pure PHP and how it handles POST data here.

Try this in your script:

```php
Request Body:
<pre><?= var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')) ?></pre>
```

*(decode from JSON to see it as an array, e.g. `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)`)*

PHP decodes POST data when `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` (in such case `php://input` is not available) but for your request type you need to handle that yourself (or use a library/framework for that).

[image]

Comment: Yes, of course. Feel myself so dumb right now, totally forgot about that.  Guess I need to refresh my knowledge of PHP. Thank you so much.